# How to get a character before last letter in NSString?

Tags: ios, nsstring

I have `NSString` with input Value from keyboard.

Eg.

```
NSString *myText = @"Apple";
```

In my case , i want to get a word before last letter.

For above eg , i want to get only `l` letter before `e` letter.

How can i get it?

Comment: When you say `"i want to get only l word before e word."` do you mean letter not word?

Comment: Oh sorry for my bad english. I mean letter.

Comment: No worries it just didn't make to much sense at first and I didn't want it getting closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *text = @"Apple";
unichar c = [text characterAtIndex:text.length - 2];
```

If you need a `NSString`

```
NSString *character = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&c length:1];
```

Comment: when i test it with NSLog(@"Word is %c",c); , it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 1):

that may be a useful implenentaion as well:

```
NSString *_string = @"string";

NSString *_letter = nil;
if (_string.length > 1) {
    [_string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(_string.length - 2, 1)];
}
```

it does not crash either, when the string is not long enough.